# High 4bit crash in atmega128 serial communication

Tags: microcontroller, serial, rs232

I am trying to communication between atmega128 and serialCom(PC),

but I get a pretty strange bug.

When I send data 0 to 255 (char) from atmega128 to serialCom(PC)

,after sending 0x08, the high bit is crashed. (07 -> 18)

For better understanding, I attached picture about the bug.

[image]

It is my first time coding in AVR, So I couldn't find where is my bug.

Here is my source code.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include "header.h"

unsigned char rx;

void Putch(unsigned char local_data)
{
    while(!(UCSR0A & 0x20));
    UDR0 = local_data;
}

char Getch(void)
{
    while(!(UCSR0A & 0x80));
    return UDR0;
}



void main(void)
{
    UCSR0A = 0;
    UCSR0B = (1<< RXEN0) | (1<<TXEN0); //UART0 Rx,Tx On
    //UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00) | ( 0 << UMSEL0) | ( 0 << UMSEL1) | ( 0 << UPM00) | ( 0 << UPM01);
    UCSR0C = 0x06;
    UBRR0H = 0;
    UBRR0L = 103;
    unsigned char flag = 0;
    int i = 0 ;
    while(1)
    {
        flag = Getch();

        for(i = 0 ; i < 255 ; i++)
            Putch(i);

        _delay_ms(5000);
    }
}
```

If you have any idea about this situation, please comment for me.

thx.

Comment: Do you have access to a scope or logic analyzer?

Comment: Too many magic numbers. Using the defintions for all those bits makes the code much better readable.

Comment: Too many magic number? what do you mean?

Comment: I don't know what is logic analyzer or a scope. did you means like oscilloscope?

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to write bytes into the UART tx buffer faster than they can be sent? At 9600 baud it takes about 1 ms to transmit each byte. Try putting a 2 ms delay after each call to Putch()

Comment: One of my friends said that, I did one hour ago. Unfortunately, there is no progressive. I'm still stuck with this problem. T_T

Comment: I'm just starting doubting my board which includes AVR. Is there any method for checking board problem?

Comment: Magic number in this context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Comment: thx for comment, but I just wonder why did you mention magic number. Could you explain for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self answer :

finally, I solved this problem.

The problem was baud rate.

Basically, communication in computer needs specific speed like baud rate.

baud rate would be changed according to type of AVR because of clock.

thx for all comment and hope you check on your AVR's clock and baud rate.